# Expectation - Function using normalising constant and indicator function

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions, continuity, expected-value

$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, by \ f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,x+y)$

Let $B = f^{-1}([1,4]\ \times \ [-4, \infty)\ \times \ (-2\sqrt2,2\sqrt2))$

Suppose $(X,Y)$ is a r.v. taking values in $B$ with $pdf:f(x,y)=Ce^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}I_B(x,y)$ - where C is a normalising constant.

Find $\mathbb{E}(X), \mathbb{E}^7, \mathbb{E}(|XY|(X^2+Y^2)^{-1})$

I do not understand how to approach this question. I know that for finding the expectation from a random variable, you use $\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_{_-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)dx$

So would I need to find the marginal distribution of $X$ And find then find it’s expectation?

Do I need to find the value of the normalising constant $C$?

How do I approach expectation when an indicator variable is involved? Do I find the probability of the indicator variable equalling 1 (and hence equalling 0)?

Sorry lots of questions, but this problem seems to be more difficult than others I have attempted before.